# Se puede imprimir el contenido de una página (consulta que devuelve datos) en otra página?

Tags: php, json, url, sql, axios

Explico un poco mejor mi pregunta. Necesito imprimir el body de la siguiente url: https://digital-lds-application-web-regression.frankfurt.rbdigitalcloud.com/r/document/LT-PP-US-en-Vitalmins-survey

Cabe destacar que cuando digo body es una propiedad del json. No es una página común, es una API. Donde desde el navegador con esa URL puedo acceder y ver la información, pero que pasa cuando intento mostrarla en un archivo html por ejemplo, no me la muestra.

Los pongo un poco en contexto, intente hacerlo con axios, pero tengo otras cosas que no me permiten hacerlo, por ejemplo un auth mediante un token, por lo cual también desarrolle un backend para que me realizara esto, pero al llamarlo, el navegador me comenta el código php y tampoco lo reconoce. No es un tema de extensión por las dudas, porque intente cambiandole la extensión a la página que lo presente y obtengo el mismo resultado. Comenta el código php, por lo que no se ejecuta el backend.

Les envio un los archivos a los cuales hago referencia:

test-vitalmins.php o html es el mismo codigo.

```
    <?php
    include ('C:\apps\vitalmins\vitalmins-personalised-health-us\vitalmins-personalised-health-us\app\php\actions\TokenController.php');
    include ('C:\apps\vitalmins\vitalmins-personalised-health-us\vitalmins-personalised-health-us\app\php\actions\getLDS.php');
    ?>

        <div class="js-terms-and-conditions">
            <p>Test I'm here!</p>
        </div>

            <div id="privacyPolicy">
                <?php echo $privacyP ?>
            </div>
            <div id="termsConditions">
                <?php echo $resp ?>
            </div>

        <!--<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                axios.get('https://digital-lds-application-web-regression.frankfurt.rbdigitalcloud.com/r/document/LT-PP-US-en-Vitalmins-survey')
                .then(function(response){
                console.log(response.data);

                var results = response.data["results"]["publishedPeriod"]["lastetstRevision"]["body"];

                    privacyPolicy.innerHTML += results;

                })
                .catch(function(err){
                console.log(err);
                });
            </script>
            <script>
                axios.get('https://digital-lds-application-web-regression.frankfurt.rbdigitalcloud.com/r/document/LT-TC-US-en-Vitalmins-survey')
                .then(function(response){
                console.log(response.data);

                var results = response.data["results"]["publishedPeriod"]["lastestRevision"]["body"];

                    termsConditions.innerHTML += results;

                })
                .catch(function(err){
                console.log(err);
                });
            </script>-->

</html>
```

Y por último el archivo del backend getLDS.php que estan en rutas diferentes, por eso le coloco la ruta completa, ya que al ser test-vitalmins un archivo de prueba, lo estoy ejecutando directamente desde la ruta del xampp (mi servidor local).

```
<?php

include ('php/actions/TokenController.php');

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;

/**
 * Stores user name and email
 * 
 * @param Array $data An associative array containing user's name and email address
 */

function getLDS($request){
  global $cds;

    $getLDS = new getLDS($data);
    $getLDS->get();

}

class getLDS
{
  /**
   * Create a new controller instance.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  private $data;
  private $jsonAccessToken;
  private $jsonErrors;
  public function __construct($data)
  {
      $this->data = $data;
  }

  public function get(){
      global $cds;

      $error = [];

      $message = [];
      $status = 200;

      $client = new Client([
        // Base URI is used with relative requests
        'base_uri' => $cds['CDS_URL'],
        // You can set any number of default request options.
        'timeout'  => 3.0,
    ]);
      if($this->getAuth($client)){

        $response = json_decode( $this->getTermsAndConditions() , true);
        $privacy = json_decode( $this->getPrivacyPolicy() , true);
        $success = false;
        if( $response["status"] == "ok" ){
            $success = true;
            $message = $this->getMessage(1);
        }else{
            if( $privacy["status"] == "ok" ){
                $success = true;
                $message = $this->getMessage(1);
            }else{
                $message = $this->getMessage(2);
                $status = 304;
            }
        }

            return respond($success, $message, $status);
      }
  }

  //CDS

  private function getToken($client, $token){
      global $cds;
      try{
          $resp = $client->request("POST", $cds["CDS_GET_TOKEN_URL"], [
              'headers' => [
                  'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                  'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache',
                  'Authorization' => 'Basic '.base64_encode($cds["CDS_CLIENT_ID"].':'.$cds["CDS_CLIENTID_SECRET"])
              ],
              'allow_redirects' => true,
              'form_params' => [
                  'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
                  'client_id' => $cds["CDS_CLIENT_ID"],
                  'client_secret' => $cds["CDS_CLIENTID_SECRET"],
                  'code' => $token,
                  'redirect_uri' => $cds["CDS_REDIRECT_URL"]
              ]
          ]);
          $this->jsonAccessToken = json_decode((string)$resp->getBody());
          return true;
      }catch(ClientException $e){
          return false;  
      } 
  }

  private function getTermsAndConditions(){
    global $cds;
    $client = $this->getClient($cds["CDS_GET_LDS_URL"]);

    $resp = $client->request("GET", $cds["CDS_DOCUMENT"].'/'.$cds["BUSINESS_ID"], [
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => $this->jsonAccessToken->token_type.' '.$this->jsonAccessToken->access_token
        ],
        'json' => $this->data
    ]);

    return $resp->getBody();

  }

  private function getPrivacyPolicy(){
    global $cds;
    $client = $this->getClient($cds["CDS_GET_LDS_URL"]);

    $privacyP = $client->request("GET", $cds["CDS_DOCUMENT"].'/'.$cds["BUSINESSID_PP"], [
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => $this->jsonAccessToken->token_type.' '.$this->jsonAccessToken->access_token
        ],
        'json' => $this->data
    ]);

    return $privacyP->getBody();

  }

  private function getClient($url){

    $client = new Client([
        // Base URI is used with relative requests
        'base_uri' => $url,
        // You can set any number of default request options.
        'timeout'  => 3.0,
    ]);

    return $client;
    }
}
```

Y este es el resultado que obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cualquier respuesta será de gran ayuda, igual al ingresar al link que deje pueden ver la información que deseo imprimir, pero esta es la página a la que me refiero. Abierto desde firefox...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Error CORS:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

tu error esta en el nombre de los nodes, cambia:

```
var results = response.data["results"]["publishedPeriod"]["lastetstRevision"]["body"];
```

por:

```
var results = response.data["result"]["publishedPeriod"]["latestRevision"]["body"];
```

Comment: Gracias, por tu respuesta. Ciertamente tienes razòn, pero habìa descartado axios y por eso habìa hecho el tema del backend. Porque tengo error de CORS.

Anexe la imagen!